# Error extending Diesel with wrapper type for u128

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm having difficulties with the following code where I am trying to create a custom type `U128` for `u128` which Diesel does not implement by default. My goal is to have a `u128` primitive stored in a Postgresql database either as a text format or numeric (preferably numeric).

```
use std::io::Write;
use diesel::{AsExpression, deserialize, FromSqlRow, serialize};
use diesel::deserialize::{FromSql};
use diesel::pg::{Pg};
use diesel::serialize::{IsNull, Output, ToSql};
use diesel::sql_types::{Text};

#[derive(AsExpression, FromSqlRow, Debug, Clone, Copy)]
#[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
pub struct U128(pub u128);

impl ToSql<Text, Pg> for U128 {
    fn to_sql<'b>(&self, out: &mut Output<'b, '_, Pg>) -> serialize::Result {
        write!(out, "{}", self.0.to_string())?;
        Ok(IsNull::No)
    }
}

impl FromSql<Text, Pg> for U128 {
    fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&[u8]>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
        let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(bytes.as_bytes());
        Ok(U128(s.parse()?))
    }
}
```

Here is the diesel struct I have created.

```
#[derive(Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::balance)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct Balance {
    pub id: i32,
    pub account_name: String,
    pub balance: u128,
}
```

This is the compile error I am getting when trying to use `u128` in a diesel struct.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u128: diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Text, Pg>` is not satisfied
   --> src\models.rs:117:27
    |
117 |     pub balance: u128,
    |                  ^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Text, Pg>` is not implemented for `u128`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `diesel::Queryable<ST, DB>`:
              i8
              i16
              i32
              i64
              u8
              u16
              u32
              u64
            and 2 others
    = note: required for `u128` to implement `FromSqlRow<diesel::sql_types::Text, Pg>`
    = help: see issue #48214
```

Comment: Your `Balance` struct isn't using your `U128` wrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`diesel` doesn't magically apply any wrapper that might work, that's impossible, instead you have to tell it, which intermediate type it should use with `(de)serialize_as` attributes:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::balance)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct Balance {
    pub id: i32,
    pub account_name: String,
    #[diesel(serialize_as = U128, deserialize_as = U128)]
    pub balance: u128,
}
```

for that to work, `diesel` also needs a way to convert your wrapper from/to the target type, you can provide that with the `From` trait:

```rust
impl From<u128> for U128 {
    fn from(v: u128) -> U128 {
        U128(v)
    }
}

impl From<U128> for u128 {
    fn from (v: U128) -> u128 {
        v.0
    }
}
```

---

<sup>Note: `diesel` uses [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) for conversion, but since this one is infallible and there is a chain of blanket implementations that gets us there for free, I implemented `From` instead.</sup>